# I can't see any comments in my blogger

Tags: comments, blogger

Just as in topic. I've asked Google-Staff, but they've said that they don't support problems like these because I've got "third party template". So maybe you could help me?

I've got notifications if someone comments my blog, but can't see them. I had been searching some web for some solutions but nothing works :/

Here is address: http://okiemdawidapstrak.blogspot.com

PS: I'm entirely beginner at blogging so please be patient if my problem is trivial/I won't understand something :)

Answer (score 1):

The comments from your blog are shown on your blog's "Comments RSS" page, so the comments are already on your blog's server. All you need to do is to display the comments on your blog.

There is an option on blogs being hosted with blogger to either turn ON or turn OFF comments. If your comments are not visible, do the following.

1. Log on to your blogger’s dashboard.
2. Navigate to your blog’s *Settings* -> *Comments*
3. On the *Comments* menu, select *Show* to display comments on your blog.
4. If you want to allow everyone to comment on your blog, you may select the *Anyone* option from the *Who can comment* menu.
5. To show embedded comment box below your blogger posts, select the option *Embedded below post* from the *Comment form placement* menu.

More options for showing comments are shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Goto your blogger setting and select "Embedded in page" in Comment section.